# 不適切メッセージ。

Tags: 機能の要求

此方です、
[image: 此方です、]

此は　以前、
見受けた　ものですが、
今でも　発せられ続ける、
ものでしょうか？
"

何とも、

自責外で　突発的に、
窮地に　落ち込んだ、
ものの、

其の　内心を、
前に、
省みれも　しない。
"

此は、

既に　改まったのですが？
余りに　無神経に、
すぎると　思います。
"

もし、

未だ　未対応でしたら、
既に　一部よりは、
賛同も　頂いている、
事ですし、

改めては　如何ですか？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

スタック・オーバーフローで表示される文言のほとんどは、**英語のメッセージを元にコミュニティユーザーがボランティアで翻訳活動を行っています**。

該当部分は英語の "Oops!" を直訳したものだと思われ、英語圏においてどの程度のニュアンスなのかは私も詳しく分かりませんが、確かに (訳した) "おっと！" は深刻な状況で表示されるメッセージとしてはややカジュアルな印象を受けます。

もし改善するとしたら「申し訳ありませんが…」辺りを付け加えるのも案ですが、冗長になるのでざっくり削って単に「エラーが発生しました」としてしまっても良いような気がします。
(個人的には "!" も翻訳にあたっては不要と感じます)

**原文:**

> Oops! Something Bad Happened!

前述の通り翻訳はボランティアが行っており、この辺りの細かい部分の統一見解 (=ルール) が出来ていない箇所は多々あるかもしれません。

Comment: 有り難うございます。
"
"
勿論、
"
一意の　異も、
挟む　余地なく、
賛同　致します。

Comment: あぁ、タグを　適正に、付け替えて　頂けたのですね、有り難うございます。　しかし、提案後に　しては、頂けませんか？

Comment: では、不適切と　認め、対応　頂けるのですね？